# Linux kernel- group_power

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, load-balancing

I'm trying to understand how the [load_balance](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c?v=3.14#L6115) works in the kernel (I'm checking version 3.14).

during the operation the kernel uses a struct named:
 [sg_lb_stats](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c?v=3.14#L5169) to help him represent the statics (sg_lb_stats = sched group load balance statics).

one of the parameters in the struct is group_power.
I can see its being used in many places, but cant under stand what does it represents/means, and also why it is a unsighnt long int?

example for place where it is [used](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c?v=3.14#L5862):

```
env->imbalance = min(
        max_pull * busiest->group_power,
        (sds->avg_load - local->avg_load) * local->group_power
    ) / SCHED_POWER_SCALE;
```

unfortunately, I couldn't find any information regarding this struct and its parameters,
can anyone help me?

Comment: Look at all files in `Documentation/scheduler` but pay particular attention to `sched-domains.txt`.  It gives a fair overview of what's happening [with particular reference to `load_balance`]. You may have better luck with a newer kernel. `group_power` has been renamed to `group_capacity` [which is a clue]. The newer code is usually cleaner and easier to understand.  I'd say learn on the latest stable version and then retro later on if you need to.  You're about 9 major revs back for something that is undergoing active development

Comment: Thanks Craig, but I already took a look at this doc and still things are not clear to me. I cant switch the Kernel version...

Comment: I guessed you would have to _use_ the older kernel.  But, you can _study_ the newer one [keeping an eye on older] to learn.  My point is/was that the newer version will [probably] be cleaner and easier to understand (e.g. you'd be looking at "production" vs "prototype" code).  The sym rename: the old name was a poor/confusing choice to describe its function.  I've been writing linux kernel/driver code for 20+ years and unix for additional 10+ and it's what I'd do [and do].  Also, you could clone Linus's repo [or the subtree repo for this] and look at related git log messages and diffs